# Update values in a Google sheet with values from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up some sheets to run invoicing and stock control for my business.
I have an invoice template, the sheet is called "Shop" where col A rows 22 to 41 have stock codes and col B rows 22 to 41 have the quantities to be sold.

The script I need will find the value in Shop A22 in another sheet (called "Stock" between A5 & I1000) and update the quantity in stock which is held in col 5 and the quantity sold held in col 7.

At present I have this working in Excel using the two modules shown below but I don't know how to get them to work in Sheets.

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

```
Sub UpdateStockDetailsDjB()
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intStk As Integer
    Dim strPrd As String
' Serially process cells A22 thru A41
    intRow = 22
    Do
        If Worksheets("Shop").Cells(intRow, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        Rem strPrd = Left(Trim(Worksheets("Shop").Cells(intRow, 1).Value), 5)
        strPrd = (Worksheets("Shop").Cells(intRow, 1).Value)
            intStk = fncFindPrdStk(strPrd) ' Stock Code row in ShopStock sheet
        Worksheets("Stock").Cells(intStk, 5).Value = Worksheets("Stock").Cells(intStk, 5).Value - Worksheets("Shop").Cells(intRow, 2).Value ' Update Qty in Stock
        Worksheets("Stock").Cells(intStk, 7).Value = Worksheets("Stock").Cells(intStk, 7).Value + Worksheets("Shop").Cells(intRow, 2).Value ' Update Used / Sold
        If intRow = 41 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        intRow = intRow + 1
    Loop
' End
Call Clearhop
End Sub


Function fncFindPrdStk(strPrd As String) As Variant
    Dim intRow As Integer
' Find Stock Code row in Stock sheet cells A3 thru A1010
    intRow = 3
    Do
        If Trim(Worksheets("Stock").Cells(intRow, 1).Value) = strPrd Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        If intRow = 1510 Then
            MsgBox "Stock Code MISSING: " & strPrd, vbCritical
            Exit Do
        End If
        intRow = intRow + 1
    Loop
' Return Stock Code row
    fncFindPrdStk = intRow
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

**Description**

I'm not able to test this since it relies on several sheets and specific data in particular row, and rather than try to construct a data set for testing I just have to hope I've translated everything correctly.

Any way this at least shows the basics of how I would do it.  Its a start.

What is unclear is how the function is executed.

I have tried to create test data to test this script and have made several revisions.  Please replace the script with the latest.

**Code.gs**

```
function updateStockDetailsDjB() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let shop = spread.getSheetByName("Shop");
    let stock = spread.getSheetByName("Stock");
    let stockValues = stock.getRange(5,1,1006,7).getValues(); // A5:G1010
    let shopValues = shop.getRange(22,1,20,2).getValues(); // A22:B41
    for( let i=0; i<shopValues.length; i++ ) {
      if( shopValues[i][0] === "" ) break;
      let strPrd = shopValues[i][0];
      let index = fncFindPrdStk(strPrd,stockValues);
      // Remember array index is 1 less then column number
      stockValues[index][4] = stockValues[index][4]-shopValues[i][1]; // Update Qty in Stock
      stockValues[index][6] = stockValues[index][6]+shopValues[i][1]; // Update Used / Sold
    }
    // In case there are any formulas in the columns lets extract columns E(4) an G(6)
    let column = stockValues.map( row => [row[4]] );
    stock.getRange(5,5,stockValues.length,1).setValues(column);
    column = stockValues.map( row => [row[6]] );
    stock.getRange(5,7,stockValues.length,1).setValues(column);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // If run from Spreadsheet context you could use this
    // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function fncFindPrdStk(strPrd,values) {
  // values is only up to row 1010
  let index = values.findIndex( row => row[0] === strPrd );
  if( index < 0 ) throw  "Stock Code MISSING: " & strPrd;
  return index;
}
```

**References**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [String](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)
- [Spreadsheet Best Practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Many Thanks - @TheWizEd I've added the code and thought I could just run it. It does run but with no result. You were correct with your comment of "What is unclear is how the function is executed"! Thanks all the same.

Comment: Share your spreadsheet or at least an example and maybe I can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Hi  The WizEd, Thanks for your help,  I've made up some example sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ppVGCuEaODuTMbeuvXVhwQkLfOKg00atrU27KpNKJ8U/edit?usp=sharing Regards Ben

Comment: I've updated my script which works with your data set.  You said "A5" in your OP  but "A3" in your script.  That and I made a mistake in `shopValues[i][2]`.  It should have been `shopValues[i][1]`.

Comment: - TheWizEd Many thanks that works, just got to try and piece all the other bits together now! Can you tell me how do you "call" another script depending on a cell contents please? Thanks again Regards Ben

Comment: You should post another question on stackoverflow.  That way others can contribute and see a solution if they have a similar question.